# Vector variable and single-variable gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I show that

$$
f(\overrightarrow{x}) = \nabla f( \overrightarrow{0} ) \cdot  \overrightarrow{x}
$$
for every $x$, given that  $f \space (t \cdot \overrightarrow{v})= t \space f( \overrightarrow{v})$?

I'm confused by the notion of the gradient of a single-variable function and the vector variable. I assume that since $f \space (t \cdot \overrightarrow{v})= t \space f( \overrightarrow{v})$, $\space$ $f({x})$ has the form $f({x})=ax$, but that's all I got so far. Any hints?

Comment: Why do you assume that? What if $f(x)$ was rotation by say $\pi/3$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the details to you, since this looks like homework.

Consider the function $g(t)=f(tx)$ then $g'(t)=\nabla f(tx)\cdot x$ (chain rule), but also $g'(t)= f(x)$.